# How to re-arrange opened tabs in panel?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, desktop-environments, panel, taskbar

I am using **Dash to panel** extension with **GNOME Tweaks** in Ubuntu 18.04 to move the taskbar to the bottom. But I cannot seem to be able to re-arrange opened tabs. Here's what I want to do:
[image]

Drag and drop doesn't work and it messes up the actual favorites icons. Is there a way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** It's doable in LXDE and KDE (maybe some others as well, but I only checked these). I gave Kubuntu a try, but did not find it nearly as comfortable as regular Ubuntu with GNOME. It's kind of sad that such basic feature is absent in GNOME.

**EDIT:** I recently reinstalled Ubuntu. I tested moving around the tabs today and somehow it is working now, but a bit inconsistently. I seem to be able to move around some tabs, but not all of them. The only pattern that I could find today is that it seems to be working with installed applications and not working with portable applications. I tested the following applications as of now:

**Working:** Firefox, Atom, Terminal, Gedit, Settings, GNOME Tweaks, Nemo.

**Not working:** Firefox Developer Edition, Etcher.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

unlock taskbar and re-arrange what do you want

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to accomplish this. Only permanently pinned icons, i.e., your favorites, icons that remain there whether the application is open or not, can be rearranged by drag-and-drop.

The way you configured Dock to Dock, favorite icons are used as launchers, whereas open windows appear as buttons right to the section of the launchers. The buttons (icons with text) appear in the order the windows have been opened and are not designed to be moved. On the other hand, you can rearrange the launchers (single icons) on the left.

Comment: Thanks. On a side note, can you recommend any other option (maybe some other environment) where I can re-arrange the icons?

Comment: This  answer is now definitely wrong. You can move around open applications whether they are favorites or not (Ubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 0):

1. add to favorites
2. re-arrange
3. remove from favorites (optional)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really a "lazy-friendly" procedure, hehe.

Comment: you're welcome :)
I know, but I think it's the only way to do it.